# Instance of overloaded function in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello I am trying to implement a Fast Feature Detector code,in the initial phase of it i get the following errors

(1)no instance of overloaded function "cv::FastFeatureDetector::detect" matches the argument list

(2)"KeyPointsToPoints" is undefined

Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
  Mat img1 = imread("0000.jpg", 1);
  Mat img2 = imread("0001.jpg", 1);
 // Detect keypoints in the left and right images
FastFeatureDetector detector(50);
Vector<KeyPoint> left_keypoints,right_keypoints;
detector.detect(img1, left_keypoints);
detector.detect(img2, right_keypoints);
vector<Point2f>left_points;
KeyPointsToPoints(left_keypoints,left_points);
vector<Point2f>right_points(left_points.size());

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What do the docs for your version of OpenCV say about `cv::FastFeatureDetector::detect`?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in this line:

```
Vector<KeyPoint> left_keypoints,right_keypoints;
```

C++ is case-sensitive, it sees that `Vector` is something different than `vector` (what it should really be). Why would `Vector` work is beyond me, I would have expected an error earlier.

[`cv::FastFeatureDetector::detect`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=fast#featuredetector-detect) only knows how to work with `vector`, not a `Vector`, so try to fix this bug and try again.

Also, `KeyPointsToPoints` does not exist in the OpenCV library (unless you program it yourself), make sure you use [`KeyPoint::convert(const vector<KeyPoint>&, vector<Point2f>&)`](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/classcv_1_1_key_point.html#acf14ce0e49e5fd80e18f906b3b810eea) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few small problems with the code as given. First you are missing `using namespace std` which is needed to use the vectors the way you are using them. You are also missing the include for vectors `#include <vector>`. `vector<KeyPoints>` should also have a lower case v. I'm also not sure if KeyPointsToPoints is part of OpenCV. You may have to implement this function on your own. I'm not sure, I just haven't seen it before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Mat img1 = imread("0000.jpg", 1);
Mat img2 = imread("0001.jpg", 1);
// Detect keypoints in the left and right images
FastFeatureDetector detector(50);
vector<KeyPoint> left_keypoints,right_keypoints;
detector.detect(img1, left_keypoints);
detector.detect(img2, right_keypoints);
vector<Point2f>left_points;

for (int i = 0; i < left_keypoints.size(); ++i) 
{
    left_points.push_back(left_keypoints.pt);
}
vector<Point2f>right_points(left_points.size());

return 0;
}
```

I didn't test the code above. Check out the OpenCV documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html)